# How to change font (size) for an Eclipse editor programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts, eclipse-plugin, swt

How can I change the font / the font size of an Eclipse editor programmatically?

I found out this (from within the editor):

```
this.getSourceViewerDecorationSupport(getSourceViewer()).setSymbolicFontName(name);
```

But I am not sure if this is the way to go. Furthermore I still lack of the possibility to set the font size for my editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify the 'symbolic font name' to use in the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point declaration of your editor using the 'symbolicFontName' attribute.

For example, this is the Java editor:

```xml
<extension
     id="javaeditor"
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
  <editor
        name="%CompilationUnitEditorName"
        default="true"
        icon="$nl$/icons/full/obj16/jcu_obj.png"
        contributorClass="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditorActionContributor"
        class="org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.CompilationUnitEditor"
        symbolicFontName="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.editors.textfont"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.CompilationUnitEditor">
        <contentTypeBinding
           contentTypeId="org.eclipse.jdt.core.javaSource"
        /> 
  </editor>
```

Which is defining the symbolic font name to use as `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.editors.textfont`.

The symbolic font name is a reference to a font definition in the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` extension point.

For example the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.editors.textfont` is defined as:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.themes">
  <fontDefinition
        label="%javaEditorFontDefiniton.label"
        defaultsTo="org.eclipse.jface.textfont"
        categoryId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.presentation"
        id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.editors.textfont">
     <description>
        %javaEditorFontDefintion.description
     </description>
  </fontDefinition>
```

This definition sets the font to default to be the same as the standard Text Font.

Fonts defined this way will appear in the Eclipse Preferences in 'General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts'

Comment: So there's no possibility to apply these changes at runtime?

Comment: The editor is listening for this preferences property to change and will refresh if it does. I don't see a non-internal API allowing the font to be changed.